# Extracting different tar archives into the same folder

Tags: linux, tar, archive

Suppose I have two files named `archive1.tar` and `archive2.tar` in the same directory and apparently both of them extract into a folder called `folder` containing different files for each tar archive. My question is: if I extract both archive files, will the first `folder` contents be replaced by the last to be extracted archive or will both contents be combined into `folder`?

Comment: both contents will be combined

Comment: how will they be combined? will the files be overwritten?

Comment: no unless you specify `--overwrite`